# Prometheus empty query results

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to find metric data `# HELP net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total Total number of connections attempted by the given dialer a given name.# TYPE net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total counter` but receive [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzYbG.png) . What could be the reason?

Comment: Possibly that the metric has not appeared in any scrape target's metrics. Possibility because the counter hasn't been recorded during the time the Prometheus server has been scraping it. Corollary: metrics that haven't been recorded aren't included